# Screen scraping Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to copy the contents of a NBA league table using Nokogiri but having a little trouble:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css(":contains('Western Conference')").count do |team|
  puts team .at_css("")
end
```

I'm tring to get the table from http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html and
 want just the West Conference table but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Eastern and Western conference teams are in one table, the best you can do is get all Western conference team `<tr>` tags.

```
doc.xpath("//table/tr[td//text()[contains(., 'Western Conference')]]/following-sibling::tr")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) rescue nil
@doc.css('.confTitle').each do |team|
  if team.text == "Western Conference"
    # do your stuff
  end
end
```

You can check the text of CSS and then you will save or print that data/

Comment: Be careful using a trailing `rescue nil`. It covers all exceptions that occur on that line, including anything that occurs inside Nokogiri and OpenURI. If it triggers, `@doc` will be nil, causing `@doc.css` to fail in an unexpected way. Also, `@doc` isn't necessary in an example like this, as there is no need for instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it using CSS accessors:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
table = doc.at('.genStatTable')
```

`table` now points to the top of the table.

```
rows = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(Nokogiri::HTML::Document.new)
```

`rows` is a NodeSet, which is similar to an array for our purposes.

Look into the table for the second/last cell whose `class` is `confTitle` and get its parent `<tr>`. Loop while nodes are found at this level:

```
tr = table.css('.confTitle').last.parent
while tr do
  rows << tr
  tr = tr.next
end

puts rows.to_html
```

This returns a list of all the `<tr>` nodes starting with:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="11" class="confTitle">Western Conference</td>
         </tr>
```

and ending with:

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class="team"><a href="/jazz">Utah</a></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0.250</td>
            <td>3.5</td>
            <td>1-3</td>
            <td>0-2</td>
            <td>1-2</td>
            <td>0-1</td>
            <td>1-3</td>
            <td>L 3</td>
         </tr>
```

To embed it inside a table, which might be a bit more useful:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc2 = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><table></table></body></html>')
doc2_table = doc2.at('table')

tr = doc.css('.genStatTable .confTitle').last.parent
while tr do
  doc2_table.add_child(tr.to_html) 
  tr = tr.next
end

puts doc2.to_html
```

In this, `doc2` is a stub HTML document where the nodes found can be stored/remembered.